# How to display content in React?

Tags: reactjs

How to enable and disable radio button in reactjs.

I want when we click on radio button it should enable its input box.

Suppose when i select on first Radio Button so first it should display first input box and remain disabled the other input boxes in similar way when first input box is filled enable the second input box and similarly continues.

codesanbox link -  https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-gates-clqzc?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set state on checkbox change event. As example, you can save current checkbox id, and then you can test this id for setting disable or enable for input `disabled={isDisabled("formHorizontalRadios1")}`:

```
const [currentCheckboxId, setCheckboxId] = useState("");

const setCheckbox = event => {
  setCheckboxId(event.target.id);
};

const isDisabled = id => currentCheckboxId !== id;
```

See full example in playground: https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-dubinsky-e1o8y?file=/src/App.js:1490-1535

Comment: But if i select the first radio button i don't want to display all four input box at same time.when first input box is filled enable the second input box and similarly continues.

Comment: I am update my playground for first checkbox, please see. This is what you need?

Comment: Thanks  a lot @Denis Stukalov

Comment: Hey @Denis Stukalov can you explain this line```disabled={ isDisabled("formHorizontalRadios1") || !nameInfo.formGridName }```

Comment: Hey, in this line we set field as disabled if checkbox for line is not checked or if prev field (with id formGridName) is not set